# AWK script, linefeed under Windows causing different function

Tags: awk

I have a simple AWK script which I try to execute under Windows. Gnu AWK 3.1.6.

The awk script is run with *awk -f script.awk  f1 f2* under Windows 10.

After spending almost half a day debugging, I came to find that the following two scenarios produce different results:

```
  FNR==NR{
  a[$0]++;cnt[1]+=1;next
  }
  !a[$0]
```

versus

```
  FNR==NR
   {
    a[$0]++;cnt[1]+=1;next
    }
   !a[$0]
```

The difference of course being the linefeed at line 1.

It puzzles me because I don't recall seeing anywhere awk should be critical about linefeeds. Other linefeeds in the script are unimportant.

In example one, desired result is achieved. Example 2 prints f1, which is not desred.

So I made it work, but would like to know why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs (https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Statements_002fLines.html)

> awk is a line-oriented language. Each rule’s action has to **begin** on
>   the same line as the pattern. To have the pattern and action on
>   separate lines, you must use backslash continuation; there is no other
>   option.

Note that the action only has to *begin* on the same line as the pattern. After that as we're all aware it can be spread over multiple lines, though not willy-nilly. From the same page in the docs:

> However, gawk ignores newlines after any of the following symbols and
>   keywords:
>
> ```
> ,    {    ?    :    ||    &&    do    else
> ```

In Example 2, since there is no action beginning on the same line as the `FNR == NR` pattern, the default action of printing the line is performed when that statement is true (which it is for all and only f1). Similarly in that example, the action block is not paired with any preceding pattern on its same line, so it is executed for every record (though there's no visible result for that).